# Перестали проходить запросы к MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Почему-то перестали проходить запросы к базе. Все запросы проходят нормально, а вот вчера вечером что-то стало тупить. Причём запрос идёт в файле, где куча таких запросов есть, а этот почему-то не проходит. И по всей видимости, только с 1 таблицей так!

```
$res_list_reads = mysql_query("SELECT iread FROM reads WHERE myid = '$_SESSION[usre_id]'",$db);
$row_list_reads = mysql_fetch_array($res_list_reads);
```

Answer (score 1):

$_SESSION это ассоциативный массив:

```
$res_list_reads = mesql_query("SELECT iread FROM reads WHERE myid = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}'", $db);
$row_list_reads = mysql_fetch_array($res_list_reads);
```

Или так:

```
$res_list_reads = mesql_query("SELECT iread FROM reads WHERE myid = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'", $db);
```

Comment: нет...оказалось всё в том что надо было название таблицы написать так `имя_базы_данных`.`имя_таблицы`

Comment: ну если перед этим ты не сделал mysql_select_db(), то это само собой.